# Always start NetworkManager after laptop boot with WiFi and WWAN disabled

Tags: linux, networkmanager, laptop

How to make Network managers always start (after laptop boot) with WiFi and WWAN disabled?

I prefer to always enable them manually after laptop boot for security and connection cost control reasons.

Extra info:

1. Disabling auto-connect is not a valid option **in my case** as WWAN (LTE) connection is unstable (breaks too frequently) See https://serverfault.com/a/1112325/163277

Answer (score 1):

Set `connection.autoconnect` property to `no` for the relevant connections using `nmcli`, i.e.:

```
nmcli conn mod <conn-name-or-uuid> connection.autoconnect no
```

Comment: It is not a valid option **in my case**. WWAN (LTE) connection is unstable (breaks  too frequently).